# Trouble with checkbox, mysql, and php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to use a checkbox on a form and want to save the value as 1 or 0 in my DB.

In my DB, I have a field called "subscribe" with the following attributes:

```
TINYING(4)
Not Null
Default value = '0'
```

In my html form, I have the the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="subscribe" checked>Subscribe to our newsletter<br />
```

If the form is submitted in its default checked state, the record is passed to the database just fine.

If someone unchecks the checkbox, then no record is saved.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Would you need to see the php to help?

Thank you,
Nathan

Comment: Typo?  `TINYING(4)`  probably should be: `TINYINT(4)`

Comment: Yes, it was just a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: Here is the php I'm using:

$addfeedback = "INSERT INTO feedback (user, email, subscribe, comments)

VALUES('".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['subscribe']."','".$_POST['comments']."')";

$results = mysql_query($addfeedback);

Comment: Very bad to pass form data directly into the query. Google about proper escaping and SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks BloodyWorld.  This is great to know. I'm just starting out, so I imagine I'll learn how to do this properly (even more so with helpful tips like yours) -- at this point, I'm still just trying to get the basic functionality, and am confused by why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

web browsers dont send the key value pair for a checkbox that isnt checked. 
do a `print_r($_POST);` to observe this

either unsubscribe all except the posted subscribed values, or use a hidden input field to store the checkbox values you put into the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a BOOLEAN (TINYINT(1)) type for this, not TINYINT(4). And don't pass the value from the form directly into the query. Check the value with an if() and give per own variable an boolean to the query. Something like this:

```
$subscribe = 0;

if(isset($_POST['subscribe']) && $_POST['subscribe'] == "1")
  $subscribe = 1;

mysql_query("... VALUES ('".$subscribed."' ...");
```

And for valid XHTML use `checked="checked"` instead of `checked`

Comment: Interesting. Okay, this sounds like a good solution. Thanks also for the valid XHTML tip. But do you know why the record is currently not being saved given how I'm doing it? I though having a default value in the DB of 0 should be fine. I'm surprised that no record at all is being stored.

Comment: The default value is only used when no value given for this. But in your query it has the value "", empty string.

Comment: So unchecked is an empty string? But why is the record rejected by the DB, instead of stored with an empty string?

Comment: Afaik is an empty string not an TINYINT(1). Or maybe its the NOT NULL.

Comment: I removed the not null, still didn't change things.